Laravel 10 + Filament v3 error Call to a member function getForeignKeyName() on null
I dont know why it's not working and I don't know where or what to look for honestly. I have the main table access_permits
structure
id
permit_id
type
user_relationship_id
vehicle_relationship_id
request_date
expire_date
status
created_at
updated_at

and this is the other table access_permit_vehicles which has the many-to-many relationship
structure:
id
access_permit_id
vehicle_id
created_at
updated_at

Vehicle Model:
public function accessPermits(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(AccessPermit::class, 'access_permit_vehicles', 'vehicle_id', 'access_permit_id');
    }

AccessPermit Model:
public function vehiclesRelationship(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
    }

    public function vehicles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Vehicle::class, 'access_permit_vehicles', 'access_permit_id', 'vehicle_id');
    }

This is the migration for access_permit_vehicles:
Schema::create('access_permit_vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('access_permit_id')->constrained('access_permits')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('vehicle_id')->constrained('vehicles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

This is for access_permits
Schema::create('access_permits', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedInteger('permit_id')->unique();  // Adjusted to unsignedInteger for proper ID type

            // Other columns as defined
            $table->string('type')->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_relationship_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('vehicle_relationship_id');
            $table->dateTime('request_date');
            $table->dateTime('expire_date');
            $table->string('status')->default(\App\Enum\PermitStatus::Active);

            $table->timestamps();

            // Foreign key constraints
            $table->foreign('user_relationship_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            // Ensure the foreign key for vehicle_relationship_id if needed
            $table->foreign('vehicle_relationship_id')->references('id')->on('vehicles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });


Is there a stack trace?

@ewokx Yes, https://anotepad.com/notes/7wfqsyhy

Sad to say that...all of this struggle was:
the method is called vehicleRelationship(), yet I called it as vehiclesRelationship()
the S was an imposter.
